# Errors in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've cloned my app from Github but I've got errors on Gemfile. So I think, this app. is still running on heroku and it said that all up to date when I've used following commands:

```
 git status 
//On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean

 git push  heroku
//Everything up-to-date
```

Also I could see output in heroku.
How to fix the error in Gemfile?
thanks.

```
//error as below:
There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: The `branch` option for `gem 'recaptcha'` is not allowed. Only gems with a git source can specify a branch. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from /home/ubuntu/workspace/typo-1/Gemfile:46
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  gem 'acts_as_tree_rails3'
 >  gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails', :branch => 'rails3'
 #
```

//Gemfile

```
env = ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || 'development'
dbfile = File.expand_path("../config/database.yml", __FILE__)

#unless File.exists?(dbfile)
#  raise "You need to configure config/database.yml first"
#else
#  conf = YAML.load(File.read(dbfile))
#  adapter = conf[env]['adapter']
#  raise "You need define an adapter in your database.yml" if adapter == '' || adapter.nil?
#  case adapter
#  when 'sqlite3'
#    gem 'sqlite3'
#  when 'postgresql'
#    gem 'pg'
#  when 'mysql'
#    gem 'sam-mysql-ruby'
#  else
#    raise "Don't know what gem to use for adapter #{adapter}"
#  end
#end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "1.9.3"

gem 'thin'
gem 'rails', '~> 3.0.10'
gem 'require_relative'
gem 'htmlentities'
gem 'json'
gem 'bluecloth', '~> 2.1'
gem 'coderay', '~> 0.9'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'RedCloth', '~> 4.2.8'
gem 'addressable', '~> 2.1', :require => 'addressable/uri'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 1.3.3', :require => 'mini_magick'
gem 'uuidtools', '~> 2.1.1'
gem 'flickraw-cached'
gem 'rubypants', '~> 0.2.0'
gem 'rake', '~> 0.9.2'
gem 'acts_as_list'
gem 'acts_as_tree_rails3'
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails', :branch => 'rails3'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'ruby-debug19'
  gem 'factory_girl', '~> 2.2'
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'simplecov', :require => false
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'cucumber'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'cucumber-rails-training-wheels'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

//edited
I took off branch but got error as below when run bundle install:
bundle install

"Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3"

Version 2.4 create the same error. So,I've changed to 2.3.0 - it went through until  another error as below:

Results logged to
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/json-1.7.5/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (1.7.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.5'` succeeds before bundling.

//editing

I've follow the answer suggested to  use the old version 1.9.2 and I be able to use command bundle install but after pushing to heroku, I've got empty page on heroku and errors as below:

//errors

```
2017-07-23T18:09:50.995656+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2017-07-23T18:09:50.995657+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2017-07-23T18:09:50.995657+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2017-07-23T18:09:50.995658+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2017-07-23T18:09:50.995659+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2017-07-23T18:09:50.995659+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2017-07-23T18:09:50.995660+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<top (required)>'
2017-07-23T18:09:51.185918+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-07-23T18:09:51.200309+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-07-23T18:09:51.845236+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=typoa.herokuapp.com request_id=7c8caa3e-8bad-4431-9da6-8ddf2f52a4d1 fwd="108.211.182.6" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-23T18:19:04.542770+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=typoa.herokuapp.com request_id=798e1c83-078a-4da6-b2cd-dfbf47b80687 fwd="108.211.182.6" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

//edited

When I took off  suggested line( with recaptcha), I could not see app. locally.
With this line I could see app. locally.

Errors without this line as below:

```
rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.17 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting


    home/ubuntu/workspace/typo-1/config/initializers/recaptcha.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Recaptcha (NameError)
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
```

In any cases, I could not push to heroku: 
Errors as below(it recommends to use the latest version of Ruby):

```
Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote:  !
remote:  !     An error occurred while installing ruby-1.9.3
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Heroku recommends you use the latest supported Ruby version listed here:
```

//edit
I could not find a working app to see the solution of  this problem...Error message as below:
http://typosphere.org/stable.tar.gz#

Comment: Switching from 2.3 to 2.4 isn't going to change that your Gemfile specifies 1.9.3... Not using versions in your Gemfile is almost guaranteed to cause problems across major Ruby version upgrades.

Comment: So, basically I need to change Gemfile specifies that would be fine with 2.3 or 2.4 and then use appropriate version  on Gemfile.   If is it correct, how to approach to it? Or maybe I need to try to pull from heroku since it work fine online or start over with the new version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- In reCAPTCHA project on Github there is not a branch rails3, so, remove that piece of your Gemfile.

> gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'

2- Since you are using ruby 2.2.x, and in Gemfile is 1.9.3 I suggest that you should install 1.9.3 (via rvm or via rvm or whatever you use to manage your ruby versions) in your machine and work with that in order to avoid other conflicts you may find, because you are using a legacy code.

> rvm install 1.9.3
>
> rvm use 1.9.3

now install gem bundler and after that blundle install your Gemfile

Comment: I've follow your suggestion using rvm command and putting gem bundler in Gemfile after this I've run bundle install not as you wrote "blundle install " and as a result I've got application error - my app got invisible(see error in main thread).

Comment: @User, my mistake about "blundle", in any case, I think you understood me (bundle) I still think that you should respect ruby version 1.9.3 in your Gemfile and try previous steps once again. About Heroku, actual default stack is heroku-16 which not support ruby 1.9.3 (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack-packages), you should change to cedar-14 stack to deploy the app. More info https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-14-stack

Comment: I've already tried your suggestion that said to remove gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails' When I've removed this line, I could not see output locally - it is no good. When I put this line back - I could see output locally but heroku provide errors. Do you have a working typo app with or without this line or you want me to try and see what happened? It would be helpful if you have a working app to share or know where to look at it.  I only find working app. on github but only with errors.

Comment: User, what you must remove is :branch => 'rails3' from gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails', :branch => 'rails3' not the entire line, so the resulting line looks like gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails' And yes, I have a working typo demo app deployed on Heroku

Comment: It doesn' work after editing this line: it work fine locally but could  not push to heroku(see error in main post that suggested to take the latest version or ruby). You wrote that your typo is deployed to heroku. My typo was deployed as well untill I've changed something locally - and them I could not deploy it anymore... It is not robust code if changing create errors. If you could do changing in your loyal old version, deploy and share your solution, then it would be helpful. Other why I assume that this is error.

Comment: how to " install gem bundler" ?
I didn't do it and want  to try - maybe it helps to push to heroku.

Comment: If you read the links I shared before you would notice that to deploy on Heroku an old ruby version 1.9.3 you must to set your app to cedar-14 and the command to do that is so clear there, anyway, from your terminal (ready to deploy to Heroku) type: heroku apps:stacks:set cedar-14, (or you can deploy your typo app specifying the name of the app) and your stack will migrate and accept to deploy in that version. It works fine! And respects the above steps :-)

Comment: Yes it works: I could see output in heroku. 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get this error using Ruby 2.4.1. I did get the same error when I changed versions to 1.9.3, as specified in the Gemfile. I also don't see a branch called `rails3` at the source on Github. I would try removing the branch option first.

```
gem 'recaptcha', require: 'recaptcha/rails'
```

Comment: I've removed branch and tried bundle install but got error as below: