# Heroku RoR project deployment : An error occurred while installing ruby-1.9.3-p551

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to deploy Ruby on Rails project with Ruby-1.9.3-p551 version but it fails on installing Ruby 1.9.3 version giving the error below:

```
 !     An error occurred while installing ruby-1.9.3-p551
 !     
 !     Heroku recommends you use the latest supported Ruby version listed here:
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
 !     
 !     For more information on syntax for declaring a Ruby version see:
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
```

Comment: Did you have a look at devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtime‌​s ? Ruby 1.9.3 reached end of life years ago and is not supported anymore by Heroku's current stack. You might want to upgrade to a supported version or use an older stack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errors in Gemfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228434/errors-in-gemfile)

Answer (score 0):

Specifically you have to tell heroku to give you the ubuntu server build with cedar-14 & then ensure the `gemfile` is reflected in the `gemfile.lock`

Details on here ... [Errors in Gemfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228434/errors-in-gemfile)

This page contains details on what you need ... https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes

Answer (score -1):

Ruby 1.9.1 reached EOL many years ago, and is not supported by Heroku anymore.
You should upgrade your ruby version.

Comment: Yes. Using a ruby version that's been marked as End of Life for several years is very bad anyway. There could be security issues, and they will never be fixed.

Comment: No, not the only solution - the the whole reason we use a gemfile is to get around issues like this & heroku has a long list of runtimes for this reason.

Comment: Heroku has a list of supported runtimes, but 1.9.x is not one of them anymore.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes