# How to login successfully in typo application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I be able to see the output in heroku by fixing errors in Gemfile

[Errors in Gemfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228434/errors-in-gemfile)

Also I could login as admin...but only one time...then my password is not recognized and login 
is not successful...
I could not save my password on admin page(error:Password doesn't match confirmation) and could not login 
using admin password provided(error:Login unsuccessful)

I've tried to create admin and password manually but got errors.

How to login using admin credential?

thanks

Errors and files related as below

//errors

```
typo-1 (master) $ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.17)
1.9.3-p551 :001 > User.create(:username => 'admin', 
1.9.3-p551 :002 >       :password => 'abc123', 
1.9.3-p551 :003 >       :password_confirmation => 'abc123') 
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: username
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activerecord-3.0.17/lib/active_record/base.rb:1565:in `block in attributes='
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activerecord-3.0.17/lib/active_record/base.rb:1561:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activerecord-3.0.17/lib/active_record/base.rb:1561:in `attributes='
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activerecord-3.0.17/lib/active_record/base.rb:1412:in `initialize'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/typo-1/app/models/user.rb:53:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activerecord-3.0.17/lib/active_record/base.rb:502:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activerecord-3.0.17/lib/active_record/base.rb:502:in `create'
        from (irb):1
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
1.9.3-p551 :004 > User.create(:username => 'admin',                                                                
1.9.3-p551 :005 >       :password_confirmation => 'abc123')                                                        
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: username
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activerecord-3.0.17/lib/active_record/base.rb:1565:in `block in attributes='
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activerecord-3.0.17/lib/active_record/base.rb:1561:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activerecord-3.0.17/lib/active_record/base.rb:1561:in `attributes='
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activerecord-3.0.17/lib/active_record/base.rb:1412:in `initialize'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/typo-1/app/models/user.rb:53:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activerecord-3.0.17/lib/active_record/base.rb:502:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activerecord-3.0.17/lib/active_record/base.rb:502:in `create'
        from (irb):4
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
1.9.3-p551 :006 >
```

//controllers/admin/users_controller.rb

```
    class Admin::UsersController < Admin::BaseController
      cache_sweeper :blog_sweeper

      def index
        @users = User.order('login asc').page(params[:page]).per(this_blog.admin_display_elements)
      end

      def new
        @user = User.new
        @user.attributes = params[:user]
        @user.text_filter = TextFilter.find_by_name(this_blog.text_filter)
        setup_profiles
        @user.name = @user.login
        if request.post? and @user.save
          flash[:notice] = _('User was successfully created.')
          redirect_to :action => 'index'
        end
      end



    def edit
        @user = params[:id] ? User.find_by_id(params[:id]) : current_user

        setup_profiles
        @user.attributes = params[:user]
        if request.post? and @user.save
          if @user.id = current_user.id
            current_user = @user
          end


        flash[:notice] = _('User was successfully updated.')
              redirect_to :action => 'index'
        end
      end

      def destroy
        @record = User.find(params[:id])
        return(render 'admin/shared/destroy') unless request.post?

        @record.destroy if User.count > 1
        redirect_to :action => 'index'
      end

      private

      def setup_profiles
        @profiles = Profile.find(:all, :order => 'id')
      end
    end
```

//models/user.rb

```
    require 'digest/sha1'

    # Typo user.
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      include ConfigManager

      belongs_to :profile
      belongs_to :text_filter



     delegate :name, :to => :text_filter, :prefix => true
      delegate :label, :to => :profile, :prefix => true

      has_many :notifications, :foreign_key => 'notify_user_id'
      has_many :notify_contents, :through => :notifications,
        :source => 'notify_content',
        :uniq => true

      has_many :articles, :order => 'created_at DESC'



    serialize :settings, Hash

      # Settings
      setting :notify_watch_my_articles,   :boolean, true
      setting :editor,                     :string, 'visual'
      setting :firstname,                  :string, ''
      setting :lastname,                   :string, ''
      setting :nickname,                   :string, ''



    setting :description,                :string, ''
      setting :url,                        :string, ''
      setting :msn,                        :string, ''
      setting :aim,                        :string, ''
      setting :yahoo,                      :string, ''
      setting :twitter,                    :string, ''
      setting :jabber,                     :string, ''
      setting :show_url,                   :boolean, false
      setting :show_msn,                   :boolean, false
      setting :show_aim,                   :boolean, false
      setting :show_yahoo,                 :boolean, false



    setting :show_twitter,               :boolean, false
      setting :show_jabber,                :boolean, false
      setting :admin_theme,                :string,  'blue'

      # echo "typo" | sha1sum -
      class_attribute :salt

      def self.salt
        '20ac4d290c2293702c64b3b287ae5ea79b26a5c1'
      end



    attr_accessor :last_venue

      def initialize(*args)
        super
        self.settings ||= {}
      end


      def self.authenticate(login, pass)
        find(:first,


        :conditions => ["login = ? AND password = ? AND state = ?", login, password_hash(pass), 'active'])
      end

      def update_connection_time
        self.last_venue = last_connection
        self.last_connection = Time.now
        self.save
      end



    # These create and unset the fields required for remembering users between browser closes
      def remember_me
        remember_me_for 2.weeks
      end

      def remember_me_for(time)
        remember_me_until time.from_now.utc
      end

      def remember_me_until(time)
        self.remember_token_expires_at = time
        self.remember_token            = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{email}--#{remember_token_expires_at}")
        save(:validate => false)
      end

      def forget_me
        self.remember_token_expires_at = nil
        self.remember_token            = nil
        save(:validate => false)
      end

      def permalink_url(anchor=nil, only_path=false)
        blog = Blog.default # remove me...

        blog.url_for(
          :controller => 'authors',


         :action => 'show',
          :id => login,
          :only_path => only_path
        )
      end

      def self.authenticate?(login, pass)
        user = self.authenticate(login, pass)
        return false if user.nil?
        return true if user.login == login



     false
      end

      def self.find_by_permalink(permalink)
        self.find_by_login(permalink).tap do |user|
          raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound unless user
        end
      end

      def project_modules
        profile.project_modules
      end

      # Generate Methods takes from AccessControl rules
      # Example:
      #
      #   def publisher?
      #     profile.label == :publisher
      #   end



    AccessControl.roles.each do |role|
        define_method "#{role.to_s.downcase}?" do
          profile.label.to_s.downcase == role.to_s.downcase
        end
      end



    def self.to_prefix
        'author'
      end

      def simple_editor?
        editor == 'simple'



    end

      def password=(newpass)
        @password = newpass
      end



    def password(cleartext = nil)
        if cleartext
          @password.to_s
        else
          @password || read_attribute("password")


     end
      end

      def article_counter
        articles.size

  end



def display_name
    name
  end

  def permalink
    login
  end

  def to_param
    permalink
  end

  def admin?
    profile.label == Profile::ADMIN
  end

  protected

  # Apply SHA1 encryption to the supplied password.
  # We will additionally surround the password with a salt
  # for additional security.
  def self.password_hash(pass)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{salt}--#{pass}--")
  end

  def password_hash(pass)
    self.class.password_hash(pass)
  end

  before_create :crypt_password

  # Before saving the record to database we will crypt the password
  # using SHA1.
  # We never store the actual password in the DB.
  # But before the encryption, we send an email to user for he can remind his
  # password
  def crypt_password
    send_create_notification
    write_attribute "password", password_hash(password(true))
    @password = nil
  end

  before_update :crypt_unless_empty

  # If the record is updated we will check if the password is empty.
  # If its empty we assume that the user didn't want to change his
  # password and just reset it to the old value.
  def crypt_unless_empty
    if password(true).empty?
      user = self.class.find(self.id)
      write_attribute "password", user.password
    else
      crypt_password
    end
  end

  before_validation :set_default_profile

  def set_default_profile
    if User.count.zero?
      self.profile ||= Profile.find_by_label('admin')
    else
      self.profile ||= Profile.find_by_label('contributor')
    end
  end

  validates_uniqueness_of :login, :on => :create
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :on => :create
  validates_length_of :password, :within => 5..40, :if => Proc.new { |user|
    user.read_attribute('password').nil? or user.password.to_s.length > 0
  }

  validates_presence_of :login
  validates_presence_of :email

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_length_of :login, :within => 3..40


  private

  # Send a mail of creation user to the user create
  def send_create_notification
    begin
      email_notification = NotificationMailer.notif_user(self)
      EmailNotify.send_message(self, email_notification)
    rescue => err
      logger.error "Unable to send notification of create user email: #{err.inspect}"
    end
  end
end
```

//editing: replacement user_id to login

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.17)
1.9.3-p551 :001 > User.create(login: 'admin', password: 'password123', password_confirmation: 'password123')
 => #<User id: nil, login: "admin", password: nil, email: nil, name: nil, notify_via_email: nil, notify_on_new_articles: nil, notify_on_comments: nil, profile_id: 3, remember_token: nil, remember_token_expires_at: nil, text_filter_id: "1", state: "active", last_connection: nil, settings: {}> 
1.9.3-p551 :002 > exit
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message you don't have `username` field in your `User` model.

`ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: username`

I think you are using attribute `login` in your model. Try to replace `username` with `login` and see if that works.

```
User.create(login: 'admin', password: 'password123', password_confirmation: 'password123')
```

or you can post schema for User model and we can have a look.

Comment: I've change the code(see edition in the bottom of themain post) and there are no errors. But I still could not login using console credential - it said "Login unsuccessful" ... There are no schema for User model but a lot of files under  db/migrate related to user. What file/if any need to change?

Comment: Actually there are errors in new output #<User id: nil, login: "admin", password: nil,..) 
user_id and password are not supposed to be till...

Answer (score 0):

Typo is an old legacy insecure  app  which no one particularly  supporting.

Also this version doesn't  support email and login credentials in the first place.

That why you can only login  using initial credentials and got error if you want to renew this credentials.

The latest version of typo (now called publify):

https://github.com/publify/publify

This  version supposed to support email  and supposed to  be maintained.